# Safari trust settings for Symantec certs

Tags: ios, ssl, safari

With the Symantec CA certs being distrusted by Chrome and others, will either iOS or Safari distrust certs issues by the CA at some point?

Currently, I have an iOS and Android app that show a few web pages using in-app browsers and make other network requests and am curious if there are any deadlines we need to work toward like 9/28 on Chrome.
https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html

I see that iOS 11 still has Symantec level 1-3 trusted. Does that mean it's good until at least iOS 12?
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208125

The apps are also cert pinned so we can't just change them out on the server, otherwise all the builds out in the wild would break.

Comment: Why does it matter what Safari does? If your app does cert pinning then just remove Symantec certs from the pin set and that's that.

Comment: We also show a couple things in in-app browsers. I guess the cert pinning wasn't super relevant to the root question.

Comment: I still don't see how or what Safari or iOS trust affects anything you do.

Comment: Because in-app browsers use Safari under the hood. If the system stops trusting our cert, I assume any webpages we show internally would have issues.

Comment: So your server uses a Symantec cert?

Comment: Yes. That will definitely change. Just trying to plan for the transition.